# QueueingBasicConsumer is deprecated. Which consumer is better to implement RabbitMq .net client

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

In the RabbitMQ .NET client, `QueueingBasicConsumer` is deprecated.

They recommend to use `EventingBasicConsumer` instead. I implemented the `IQueueingBasicConsumer` interface for the same way they did and it works well.

However, I am curious to why it is deprecated and why I should use `EventingBasicConsumer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think (I might be wrong!) it's done because of performance reasons. `QueueingBasicConsumer` [uses](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/api/QueueingBasicConsumer.cs) `SharedQueue<T>` which is basically .NET `Queue` with locks. In order to handle a delivery, you need to lock on queue, enqueue an item and notify other threads waiting for the queue (Monitor.Pulse).

`EventingBasicConsumer` [doesn't](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/events/EventingBasicConsumer.cs) use any queueing mechanism. It simply fires Received (HandleBasicDeliver) event which you need to handle in your code.

As you can see now `EventingBasicConsumer` has less performance overhead, so it's faster (it should be).

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I simply used `QueueingBasicConsumer ` for messaging module in my application. I need to update client and re implement with `EventingBasicConsumer`.

Answer (score 6):

Read this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/41bG-tLbwZg).  Michael Klishin is the maintainer of .NET RabbitMQ client on GitHub.

But if you don't feel like going to different links and reading there I'll summarize...

QueingBasicConsumer does not autorecover in current version, and it was a work around for a message dispatcher issue which no longer exists. But also I think Alexey is right, the performance was probably an issue too with the locking and busy waiting (in most implementations) the queue was introducing.